# What is the new Change Detection Strategy for ngIf in Angular 4 RC1?

Tags: angular

I've been using `setTimeout()` to delay a component from entering the DOM for a long time now. For example:

```
<div *ngIf="ready"><loading-template></loading-template></div>

setTimeout(() => this.ready = true, 800);
```

That is, if the data hasn't arrived, wait about 800ms before displaying a loading message. I did that to prevent flashing, according to the comments I made back in the Alpha days.

This no longer works in Angular 4 RC1. I can add ChangeDetectorRef and kick it off that way:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.read = true;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}, 800);
```

This works fine, except now I have to handle the case that the view is destroyed before calling `detectChanges();`

After glancing at the source code, I'm still unsure of what has changed. This isn't a dealbreaker, but I found it interesting enough to ask here if anyone else is experiencing the same behavior. I'm also going to follow the advice of the Contributing docs and just tag this with *angular*, even though I can see that the *angular4* tag already has 8 questions. For shame. ;-)

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/PvOoXGRN2BqSIumvmZYm?p=preview

Comment: @estus I didn't realize that, thanks. I was just trying to stay ahead of the curve because of [this article](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html).

Comment: @JBNizet That's great to know. Let me see what else I can find out.

Comment: @JBNizet [Here is another plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/NmWwyfJ5qsDaLZgDKCPZ?p=preview) that shows the issue I'm having. Behaves normally, but if you edit *loading.component.ts* and change `this.ready: boolean = true;` to `false`, you should see the issue I'm talking about. Perhaps it's something to do with the new *if else* things going on with `*ngIf`.

Comment: Very strange indeed. I added a console log in the callback of setTimeout, and it's called 10 times (instead of just one): http://plnkr.co/edit/AyCwaNyMgXbmqIT1Aoj9?p=preview. It looks like a new instance is created on a regular basis and replaces the previous one. You should definitely submit that as a bug to angular (if it hasn't been submitted yet).

Comment: A bug has been submitted for this issue (not by me): https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14873